# Japanese child's movie about a little telekinetic space prince who has a birthmark in the form of a purple star on his chest

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's from the 1980(?) and was a live action movie about a little boy from outer space which also happens to be a prince. He has a birthmark in the form of a purple star on his chest and can perform telekinesis.

People try to capture him and he's with two comic relief goons who also happen to protect him.

The final bits I remember are battle sequences with anime mechs edited into the live action locations. One mech resembles a crab because it had pincers, the other mech could extend his torso to become a dragon's maw.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JoJo%27s_Bizarre_Adventure - JoJo had a star birthmark